# SQL Server Execution Plan

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, clustered-index, nonclustered-index

In the following queries the `Student` table has Clustered Index on `StudentID` column, and the `Enrollment` Table also has a Clustered Index on `EnrollmentID` as well as Non-Clustered index on (`SessionID`, `SemesterID`, `ShiftID`, `OtherSemester`).

**First Query**
[image]

**Second Query**
[image]

Why the second plan uses look up while both `OtherSemester` and `ShiftID` are included in non-clustered index? Why the second query does not have the plan like the first query?

Comment: First Query: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJmue3xoX
Second Query: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Syp9lnxo7

Comment: There are several Non-Clustered Index created by the database engine,  including _dta_index_Enrollment_6_1515204498__K3_K4_K1_K2_K16 which does not include ShiftID, But I created another  Non-Clustered Index by the name of OtherTablesIDs which includes ShiftID.

Comment: I deleted all non clustered indexes created by the DB Engine and create one non clustered index which includes the `ShiftID` and `OtherSemesterID` columns. I run the second query again and it worked used  the same execution plan as first query.